# How to start Jetty from command line with different ports for http and https

Tags: http, command-line, https, jetty, port

I already use `-Djetty.port=xxx` to set the http port on command line but I also need to specify a different port for https. I got some hints online about `jetty.ssl.port` and aleady tried `-Djetty.ssl.port=yyy` but that did not work.

As to why provide ports on command line versus the config xml file, it's because depending on some conditions I need to start Jetty on certain ports.

I'm using Jetty 6.1-SNAPSHOT.

Ultimately I need something like:  `java -Djetty.port=XXX -Djetty.ssl.port=YYY -jar start.jar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note...that is really old version of jetty, we are releasing milestones for jetty 9 today even.

regardless, look in the jetty.xml and you should see where there is a property defined for jetty.port, just make a similar property for jetty.ssl.port or the like and then use that.

the jetty.xml file should be very easy to read, though thinking back you might need to look in the jetty-ssl.xml file.

Comment: ah, that did it. In my `jetty.xml` I had `jetty.port` in my both socketConnector sections. I changed SslSocketConnector to have `jetty.ssl.port` and used `java -Djetty.port=XXX -Djetty.ssl.port=YYY -jar start.jar` to kick it off. Thank you.

And sorry about using an old version of jetty. That came bundled with solr. I guess when we update solr we update jetty too.

Answer (score 2):

1. first do:

   mvn package
2. To start the server with default port: 8080 do

   mvn jetty: run
3. To specify an alternative port: 8090

   mvn jetty: run -Djetty.port=8090
4. To specify multiple transfer protocol port

   mvn jetty: run -Djetty.port=8090 -Djetty.ssl.port=8555

Answer (score 0):

Simply execute the following from the project directory:
`mvn -Djetty.port=8686 jetty:run`